# How to integrate two [HttpPost] with the same actionresult name? (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What i want to do:

Use two httpPost action results, they have the same name (Index) for now.. but when i change the name of either of them and i run the code, nothing happens.  how should i rework my code so that all my actionresults run?

```
       [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        ViewBag.hello = "hello world";

        var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadImageAsync(photo);
        ViewBag.Ult = imageUrl;
        //TempData["LatestImage"] = imageUrl;
        return View("Index");



    }
```

The above code is my first Index actionresult, it runs fine alone, but when i put another one, all hell breaks loose:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ModelVariables model)
    {  //code
}
```

Summary:
I want to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase photo + Modelvariables model)
    {  //code
}
```

I just want to have one httpPost method, but to include 'photo' and 'model'

Comment: You can't have 2 `[HttpPost]` methods with the same name. What is it your trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke hey there, i dont intentionally want two httpost methods... i just dont know how to use Index(HttpPostedFileBase photo and Index(ModelVariables model) at the same time...

Comment: Just have one method with 2 parameters - `Index(HttpPostedFileBase photo, ModelVariables model)` or better still, include a property `HttpPostedFileBase photo` in your `ModelVariables` view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke omg it worked and that was so simple, post an answer so i can give you a thumbs up and mark 'answered' :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 `[HttpPost]` methods with the same name. Assuming you have a form with controls for `Modelvariables` plus a file input, then add both parameters in you POST method

```
public ActionResult Index(ModelVariables model, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
```

or better still, add property `public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }` to you `ModelVariables` class so that you can use just

```
public ActionResult Index(ModelVariables model)
```

Comment: if i add the property 'public httppostedfilebase Photo {get; set;}' how do i work with public async Task<ActionResult> Index?

Comment: It will be just `public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ModelVariables model)` (and to get the file, use `var photo = model.Photo;`)

Comment: thanks, i got a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782509/getting-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-blob-storage

Comment: Cant help with that one, but you need to show the code that throws that exception if you want others to help