# Getting error when trying to connect to blob storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is the error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role
>   environment . INITIALIZING
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role
>   environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024894
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment .
>   FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024894
>
> Getting "StorageAccountName" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
>
> Getting "StorageAccountName" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.
>
> Getting "StorageAccountKey" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
>
> Getting "StorageAccountKey" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.

Okay what is this and how do i fix it?

> Info:
>
> MVC application with azure blob connection.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

The solution was to set the "Startup Project" to the Cloud Service (little cloud icon) and not the website.

Doing this meant that Visual Studio deployed the cloud configuration to the compute emulator when I started the debugger. Previously, I had the website as the startup project.

The clue was the -2147024894 error message (aka 0x80070002) - File not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your website even outside the local cloud service. The key is simply to have the values on the web.config of your application.

So in your case simply add the values for "StorageAccountName" and "StorageAccountKey" as AppSettings and CloudConfiguration.GetSetting will find them.